# How can I reduce the Linking (and Relinking) time of MinGW with Qt/QtCreator?

Tags: c++, qt, compilation, linker, mingw

I have a program which has grown in size over the period of a couple of years.  As it has grown, the time to compile and link have grown.  For a program of roughly 100k lines, it is now taking somewhere around 8 minutes for a complete rebuild and *almost 3 minutes to relink if a single file has changed*.  The catch? Running the same build on Linux takes a mere 3 minutes with a practically non-existent linking time.

Some more information:

- Both compilations are performed on computers with relatively the same specifications (RAM, CPU speed, cores, etc...)
- MinGW must be used in order to maintain low-level compiler compatibility (such things as `__attribute__((packed))` are used in order to ensure minimum packet sizes between programs
- I am locked into using MinGW-810 or greater 32 and 64-bit Qt 5.15.2 due to several reasons
- Many small static libraries are used as part of the build process (the main code is around 60k lines with the remainder being packaged into many small statically compiled libraries).
- CMake is used for compilation

The problem isn't so much with the initial build, but the relinking time is simply too much.  How can I reduce the linking and relinking time to something closer to what I experience on Linux without changing compilers or having to do something crazy like cross compile for Windows on Linux?

Comment: Have you tried creating a virus scanner exception for the entire development tree (source, build and 3rd party libraries) ?

Comment: Sorry, I have tried that as well.  I will add it to my list of things tried and failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Researching this issue led me down a lot of different paths, so I'd like to share my experience with others in the hopes of saving you days and/or weeks of trying at this.  Let me start with the solution, and then I'll go back to explain the alternatives that I worked through:

**Solution:**

The solution is to download the [LLVM Compiler Infrastructure](https://llvm.org/) and quite literally copy and paste the `lld.exe` from the installation path directly into your Qt toolchain.  For example, if your Qt installation is located here: `C:\Qt\` then copy `lld.exe` into `C:\Qt\Tools\mingw810_32\bin` (for 32-bit), **rename it** to `ld.exe` and rebuild your application.  This reduced my relinking time from approximately 2 minutes 45 seconds down to 10 seconds, *with* Qt MOC.

*Notes:*

I'm still looking more closely at how Qt searched for the linker. I started renaming all `ld.exe` files and found that simply renaming the file didn't necessarily stop Qt from linking.  That is, to discern which `ld.exe` precisely to copy over, I would rename the `ld.exe` in the 32-bit mingw directory to `ld.exe.bak`.  The program, being compiled for 32-bits, would still link successfully.  This may indicate that the CMake/Qt toolchains are capable of picking the 64-bit `ld.exe`, though I'm not yet certain of this.

**Other Attempts:**

- *-fuse-ld=lld*: I'm not a Windows guy and while it turns out that this linker flag works for MinGW 11, even when adding lld.exe to Window's PATH, I was unable to get this linker to be recognized.  My goal here was to alter the linker without having to play directly with the Qt installation.
- *PIMPL*: I went through the entirety of the program, ensuring that every single struct, every single class, was properly forward declared where possible, reducing the number of headers included within headers.  Additionally, I ensured that where abstraction could take place, it did.  We had been practicing this all along, so the change was about as great as I had expected.
- *Static Library of Static Libraries*: [Elsewhere it was suggested that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557356/tips-on-reducing-c-linking-time) one may reduce linking times by making a large static library which contains other static libraries. This turned out to have no effect whatsoever.
- *Anti-Virus Scan/Windows Defender Exception*: It was postulated in [the comment section here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70751584/extremely-long-linking-time-on-windows-but-not-linux) that part of the issue could be related to anti-virus scans.

Some other helpful resources:

- [This reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/hj66pd/c_is_too_slow_to_compile_can_you_share_all_your/)

I hope this helps someone else who might be struggling with relinking times.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works. I have also replaced objcopy.exe . My linking accelerated 5-6 times.

Comment: This hint reduced my linking time from >2 minutes to 9 seconds.